# AWS google api authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, google-oauth

I have a script in python that will run once a day and delete all files in g-drive in a particular folder.
I have tested it on my local machine and it asked me to login using my gmail account. I did that and created a credentials file so I don't have to login each time I run the script.

I'm now trying to create a lambda function in AWS and trigger it once a day. I have created deployment package, uploaded it and it seems to be running however it keeps trying to open a browser to login to g-drive again. Here's what I found in the logs:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=removed from this example
If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter
--noauth_local_webserver
```

Here's the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

def list_folders(drive_id):
    body = {'teamDriveId': drive_id}
    parent = "parent_id"
    drives = service.files().list(corpora="teamDrive", teamDriveId=drive_id, includeTeamDriveItems=True, supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='files').execute().get('files')
    for drive in drives:
        if parent in drive['parents']:
            service.files().delete(fileId=drive['id'], supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()
    print("Deleted all files!")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    list_folders("0k9PVA")(not real id)
    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

I uploaded both client_secret.json and credentials.json generated on my local machine to AWS lambda function and thought it'd work since the creds are already there and this runs fine on my machine. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was wrong. Permissions to credentials.json file were insufficient and couldn't be read. Before zipping and uploading the file to Lambda I had to change change the permissions. This solved the issue.

Comment: What permissions did you have to give? I'm having this issue too.

Comment: @LewisLebentz change the permissions to the file credentials.json. I think I used 775.

Comment: Hello, you mean unix permissions or AWS IAM permissions?